# Detecting and removing space type with PHP

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function to detect and remove space type?

Example:

**1 2 3 4 5  C i t y n a m e**

Comment: and your expected output is "12345Cityname"? if so @bedtime21 has the answer below

Comment: @MarkBaker You might want to revisit that comment before the 5 mins runs out

Answer (score 0):

Space as in ' '? Are you looking for ' 'hello this' ' and getting rid of trailing spaces? or do you want to have for example ' 'hello this' ' turn to hellothis?

If so,  str_replace(' ', '', $string)

Comment: the example shows postcode and cityname. What i'm trying to do is to separate the postcode from cityname and to get rid from spaces of each of them. From   1 2 3 4 5  C i t y n a m e   to 12345 Cityname.